# DiD with time invariant and time variant treatment?

Tags: difference-in-difference, time-varying-covariate, heterogeneity

I am currently working on a project that seeks to study the impact of the subprime crisis on family firms and non-family firms. In this, I have imagined to use a DiD estimator to account for differences in how family firms, versus non-family firms were affected by the crisis.

However, in this design, both groups receive the treatment, whereas one (family firms) are also subject to a time invariant treatment. Therefore, as I am currently considering it, we essentially have four states:

1. Pre-crisis, non-family firm (i.e., crisis = 0, family business treatment = 0)
2. Pre-crisis, family (i.e., crisis = 0, family business treatment=1)
3. Post-crisis, non-family firm (i.e., crisis=1, family business treatment = 0)
4. Post-crisis, family firm (i.e., crisis=1, family business treatment = 1)

Where I essentially want to compare the crisis coefficient of 3) and 4).

What I am now asking is: Does it make sense to conduct a DiD in this setting, given that there are essentially two treatments? (Family business, and the subprime crisis). Are there any competing approaches that I am currently overlooking?

I hope that I made myself clear.

Sincerely
Johan Karlsson

Comment: Followup question: Could this perhaps be resolved through use of firm fixed effects, hence removing the "family business" treatment, after which we can estimate the impact of the crisis for family, versus non-family firms?

Comment: Just to be clear, do both *family* firms and *non-family* firms experience a crisis (i.e., treatment/shock) in the post-period?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Thank you, sorry that I had not made this clear in my first post. Yes! Both groups are struck by the crisis simultaneously.This is the main source of my grievance, since there's no clear cut treated vs. untreated. I have done some further thinking and reading, and I am currently considering whether it would be more appropriate to use RDD for each group separately, and then compare the ATE?

Comment: Possibly. What threshold or cutoff point will be determining treatment assignment? Doesn't the mortgage crisis impact all firms in a particular industry? Only you can answer these questions.

Comment: Dear Thomas, my apologies for the late reply. The threshold for determining treatment assignment is based on industry sales shocks in the 2007-2009 period, where all firms within an affected industry are denoted as "treated".

Answer (score 1):

> I essentially want to compare the crisis coefficient of 3) and 4).

You can do this. However, you will only be comparing *family* firms with *non-family* firms. Both types of firms ‘turn on’ in the post-period.

> Does it make sense to conduct a DiD in this setting, given that there are essentially two treatments?

No, and not because you have more than one treatment. Let me elaborate. The "crisis" (i.e., treatment) is firm-invariant. In other words, you do not have a group of "unexposed" firms. If I understood your post properly, the subprime shock impacts family firms *and* non-family firms. Note: difference-in-differences requires you to observe at least some unexposed firms over time (i.e., before *and* after the subprime crisis).

Your second "business" treatment is a *time-invariant* exposure specific to *family* firms—only. The problem here is the absence of any pre-treatment observations for family firms. Your family firms are, in essence, always treated. A firm fixed effect would help adjust for this, but then we're back to a mortgage crisis experienced by all firms in your sample. If the subprime crisis impacts a subset of firms at different times, then maybe you could exploit variation in treatment timing. It appears, though, treatment exposure is well-defined, so I don't think you can take this route either. In sum, difference-in-differences does not seem valid in my estimation.